# Add label after looping number

Tags: java, sorting, for-loop

I made this code to calculate numbers:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Sorting {
private double[] player;
private int k=5;
private int j=5;

public void sort(){
    player = new double[k];
    for(int i=1;i<k;i++){
        double tempp ;
            for(i=1;i<j;i++){
                tempp = Math.random() * i;
                player[i]=tempp;
                System.out.println("Result "+i+"="+player[i]);
            }
        }
} 

public static void main(String []args){
    Sorting k=new Sorting();
    k.sort();
}}
```

and the result is:

```
Result 1=0.4529689730194949
Result 2=0.09643822768644617
Result 3=1.841047494651026
Result 4=2.1807153629323777
```

Now, I want to add a label from the biggest to the smallest result number labeled EXCELLENT, VERY GOOD, GOOD and BAD like this:

```
Result 1=0.4529689730194949 labeled GOOD
Result 2=0.09643822768644617 labeled BAD
Result 3=1.841047494651026 labeled VERY GOOD
Result 4=2.1807153629323777 labeled EXCELLENT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Sorting
{
    private double[] player;
    private int k=5;
    private int j=5;

    String[] rating = {"BAD", "GOOD", "VERY GOOD", "EXCELENT"};

    public void sort()
    {
        player = new double[k];

        for(int i=1; i<k; i++)
        {
            double tempp;
            for(i=1; i<j; i++) // i should probably be zero since your array starts on value 0, not 1.
            {
                tempp = Math.random() * i;
                player[i]=tempp;
                System.out.println("Result " + i + " = " + player[i] + " Rating is " + rating[(int)player[i]]);
            }
        }
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Sorting k = new Sorting();
        k.sort();
    }
}
```

your code seems a little odd but i fixed the problem you were asking about.

Comment: it doesn't work.  output:                                       Result 1 = 0.4239293025911335 Rating is BAD              
Result 2 = 0.12615687896767414 Rating is BAD             
Result 3 = 1.7011063570530087 Rating is GOOD             
Result 4 = 3.564207803411521 Rating is EXCELENT

Comment: how it that not what you asked for? i wrote "rating is" instead of "labeled", my bad, but you can change that easy.

Comment: in the output Result 1 = 0.42147243618671204 Rating is BAD
Result 2 = 0.3741348725996376 Rating is BAD
Result 3 = 2.868010636944234 Rating is VERY GOOD
Result 4 = 3.0166777412080044 Rating is EXCELENT , it's double result labeled BAD,  thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

TreeSet already sort the numbers ascending by default.

Here my version:

Sample output:

**Result: 0.12754837127918317 => BAD

Result: 0.7956890627771006 => EXCELLENT

Result: 0.3123868511945034 => GOOD

Result: 0.6332109887264882 => VERY_GOOD**

```
public class FourRandomNumbersEvaluator {

    private TreeSet<Double> numbers;

    private Map<Double,Evaluation> numbersWithEvaluations = new HashMap<Double,Evaluation>();

    private enum Evaluation {BAD, GOOD, VERY_GOOD, EXCELLENT}

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_GENERATED_NUMBERS = 4;


    public FourRandomNumbersEvaluator(TreeSet<Double> numbers) {
        if(numbers == null || numbers.size() != 4){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("your have to provide exactly 4 numbers");
        }
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FourRandomNumbersEvaluator evaluator = new FourRandomNumbersEvaluator(generateNumbers());
        evaluator.evaluate();
        evaluator.printNumbersWithEvaluations();
    }

    private static TreeSet<Double> generateNumbers() {
        TreeSet<Double> numbers = new TreeSet<Double>();
        while(numbers.size() < NUMBER_OF_GENERATED_NUMBERS){
            double number = Math.random();
            if(numberNotAlreadyExisting(numbers, number)){
                numbers.add(number);
            }
        }
        return numbers;
    }

    private static boolean numberNotAlreadyExisting(TreeSet<Double> numbers, double number) {
        return !numbers.contains(number);
    }

    public void evaluate() {
        int i = 0;
        for(Double number : numbers){
            numbersWithEvaluations.put(number, Evaluation.values()[i++]);
        }
    }

    private void printNumbersWithEvaluations(){
        for(Map.Entry<Double,Evaluation> numberWithEvaluation : numbersWithEvaluations.entrySet())
        System.out.println("Result: "+  numberWithEvaluation.getKey() + " => " + numberWithEvaluation.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: i never try TreeSet before , but its useful for me, thank you ;)

Comment: @andewor always prefer collections over arrays when possible ;)       Besides, since TreeSet ignores duplicates, I manage the case where there is a doubled value, look at the code.